# How to find the value of a single candle x bar before in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart, candlesticks

Which function schould I use to find higher high and lower low values of a single candle?

For example 30 candles before, exactly -30. Candle informations and plot them?

Thanks in advice

Comment: What do you mean by a single candle? A single candle has only one `high` and one `low` value. Do you want to get the highest high within 30 candles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the highest or lowest value for a given number of bars back, you can use `highest()` or `lowest()`:

```
h = highest(high, 30)
l = lowest(low, 30)
```

Or, if you want to get the value of exactly 30 bars ago, you can use the history reference operator `[]`:

```
h = high[30]
l = low[30]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was for close.
What if there're another parameters? How can I define the value of them?
For example this TK:

TK = math.avg(ta.lowest(TKlength), ta.highest(TKlength))
And I plotted that as a line
plot(TKk, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='TrueAvg')

How can I get exactly the Value of TK 30 bars (candles) ago?
Thanks

Comment: You can use any variable with the history reference operator. So, just use `TK[30]`.

Comment: Thank you.
And how can I put a little green dot under excatly this candle or if possible on the TK line?

Comment: Please ask another question for that with more details and your full code. We would like to have one question per post here, as it might also help others.

Comment: I did. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994000/how-to-assign-a-previous-candle-and-plot-a-dot-below

Thanks