# How to assign a previous candle and plot a dot below

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart

I had a few questions about defining some previous values of candles.

Q1. Which function should I use to find higher high and lower low values of a single candle?
For example 30 candles before, exactly -30. Candle informations and plot them?

A1. History Reference Operator `h = high[30]`

Q2. What if there're another parameters? How can I define the value of them?

A2. Also History Reference Operator [ ]

And now Q3. And how can I put a little green dot under excatly this candle or if possible on the plotted TK line?

```
res = input.timeframe(title='Time Frame', defval='15')
TKlength = input.int(10, 'Tenkansen Length', minval=1)
KJlength = input.int(30, 'Kijunsen Length', minval=1)
CSHSlength = input.int(30, 'Chikouspan Length/Horizontal Shift', minval=1)
SBlength = input.int(60, 'SenkouspanB Length', minval=1)
SAlength = input.int(30, 'SenkouspanA Length', minval=1)

TK = math.avg(ta.lowest(TKlength), ta.highest(TKlength))
KJ = math.avg(ta.lowest(KJlength), ta.highest(KJlength))
CS = close
SB = math.avg(ta.lowest(SBlength), ta.highest(SBlength))
SA = math.avg(TK, KJ)
TKk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, TK)
KJk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, KJ)
CSk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, CS)
SBk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, SB)
SAk = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, SA)


plot(TKk, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='TenkanSen')
plot(KJk, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title='KijunSen')

plot(CSk, offset=-CSHSlength, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#DDA0DD, 0), title='ChikouSpan')

SenkouA = plot(SAk, offset=CSHSlength, linewidth=1, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='SenkouSpanA')
SenkouB = plot(SBk, offset=CSHSlength, linewidth=1, color=color.new(color.purple, 0), title='SenkouSpanB')

fill(SenkouA, SenkouB, color=SAk > SBk ? color.green : color.red, transp=90)
```

Here is the indicator for Ichimoku cloud. What I actually exactly want to do is: Defining and plotting the TKk, KJk and CSk values 30 candles before and calculate if one of them abowe or under the others.

Thanks in advice.

[Here is the SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCojk.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and mark the candle you want to have this dot underneath?

Comment: I did. Thanks..

Comment: So you want to look 30 bars back from the current bar, right? Or is there a specific condition?

Comment: That's right.
Look 30 bars back for all values. Close, Tenkan, Kijun, Chikou, SenkouA and SenkouB.

Comment: Any comments..?